# MYSQL - all rows for all possibilities from table 1 and table 2

Tags: mysql, join

Table users

```
id, name
1, Jay Bob
2, An Other
```

Table pages

```
id, name, html
1, 'Welcome', 'Welcome to this page'
2, 'Goodbye', 'Thanks for visiting'
```

Table user_pages ** stores user specific version of pages **

```
user_id, page_id, html
1,        1,      'User id 1 Welcome page'
```

I basically need a query that will return me the below data set - a row for every possibility even when no data exists.

Data Set

```
user_id, page_id, html
1,        1,      'User is 1 Welcome page'
1,        2,      ''
2,        1,      ''
2,        2,      ''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the clearest way is to use subqueries and `cross join` to create a driver table:

```
select driver.user_id, driver.page_id, up.html
from (select u.id as user_id, p.id as page_id
      from users u cross join
           pages p
     ) driver left outer join
     user_pages up
     on up.user_id = driver.user_id and up.page_id = driver.page_id;
```

It is important that the `user_id` and `page_id` in the `select` clause come from the driver table and not from `user_pages`, because the latter may be `NULL`.

Comment: This is indeed what I am looking, just needed driver to be used in the ON clause for it all to work                                              >select driver.user_id, driver.page_id, up.html
>from (select u.id as user_id, p.id as page_id
>      from users u cross join
>           pages p
>     ) driver left outer join
>     user_pages up
>     on up.user_id = driver.user_id and up.page_id =  driver.page_id;

Answer (score 1):

Code bellow was tested on MySQL Server 5.6
I hope / presume that your intention is near the following:

```
USE test;

CREATE TABLE users (
id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE pages (
id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
html VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE user_pages (
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
page_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
html VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, page_id));

INSERT users (`name`) VALUES
  ('User 1'), ('User 2'), ('User 3');

INSERT pages (`name`, `html`) VALUES
  ('Welcome','Welcome to this page'),
  ('Goodbye','Thanks for visiting');

INSERT user_pages (user_id, page_id, html) VALUES
  (1,1,"First user's welcome page"),
  (1,2,"First user's goodbye page"),
  (2,1,"Second user's welcome page");

SELECT DISTINCT
  u.id  AS `u_id`,
  u.`name` AS `u_name`,
  IFNULL(x.page_id, p.id)  AS `p_id`,
  IFNULL(p.`name`,'') AS `p_name`,
  IFNULL(x.html,p.html) AS `p_html`
FROM users AS u
CROSS JOIN pages AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_pages AS x
  ON (x.user_id = u.id AND x.page_id = p.id);
```

The code above shall return specific (if exists) or general pages for each user. You can also create a view, and query from it as if it were a normal table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `user_page_details` AS
SELECT DISTINCT
  u.id  AS `u_id`,
  u.`name` AS `u_name`,
  IFNULL(x.page_id, p.id)  AS `p_id`,
  IFNULL(p.`name`,'') AS `p_name`,
  IFNULL(x.html,p.html) AS `p_html`
FROM users AS u
CROSS JOIN pages AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_pages AS x
  ON (x.user_id = u.id AND x.page_id = p.id);
```

Once you made it, your query would be quite simple:

```
SELECT * FROM user_page_details;
```

Or even

```
SELECT * FROM user_page_details WHERE u_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT up.user_id, up.page_id, up.html
FROM users u,pages p
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_pages up ON u.id=up.user_id AND p.id=up.user_id
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to display html from user_pages table and not pages, is that correct?

Comment: with this query I get 'unknown column u.id

Comment: Did you cut and paste it, or did you type it? Because, you have table "users" , right? And I'm aliasing this table with the name "u" (FROM users u), and then I'm refering to the column "id" within this table (ON u.id=up.user_id). And, "id" is a valid column within table "users" , right? Just trying to figuere out why this code wouldn't work by verifying my assumptions...